# Is there any way to prevent the next pages from changing when I edit spacings on current page?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In Microsoft Word, the common problem most of us face is when we are in the middle of a document (reviewing or formatting a page), and we delete some text or make some text small and the text from the next page starts coming to this page. 
Is there any way to prevent this from happening. Like, when I delete some text from the current page instead of bringing text from next page to this page, Word should add blank space at end of this page. 
Thank you.

Comment: Also, welcome to Super User! Don't forget to accept an answer when you feel you've gotten one that correctly answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're looking for is called a page break. It's under Insert > Pages > Page Break.

If you insert a page break, when you edit the spacing on your page it won't affect the following pages. I believe this is the behavior you're looking for. If you later add more content than will fit on one page Word will create a new page for the content to flow onto, in between the page you're working on and the rest of your document.